# JPanel size is 0/All I get is the minimize, enlarge, and close button

Tags: java, swing

I created two JPanels, one with a JTextField and label and one with a JTextArea.  I tried to put them into a JFrame, and when I ran the code all I got was the bar on top of a window with the minimize, enlarge, and close button.

class 1:

```
public TextListener() {
    newText = new TextSource();
    jp1 = new JPanel();
    stuff = new JTextArea(45, 70);
    scroll = new JScrollPane(stuff);

    stuff.setEditable(false);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    jp1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jp1.add(stuff);
    jp1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    jp1.setVisible(true);

    JFrame yo = new JFrame();
    yo.add(jp1);
    yo.setVisible(true);
}
```

class 2:

```
public TextSource() {
    jp1 = new JPanel();
    tf1 = new JTextField(8);
    lb1 = new JLabel("Text Source");

    jp1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    jp1.add(tf1);
    jp1.add(lb1);

    jp1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    jp1.setVisible(true);

    tf1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            newTextFirer(tf1.getText());
        }
    });

    JFrame yo = new JFrame();
    yo.add(jp1);
    yo.setVisible(true);
}
```

JFrame class:

```
public JFrameExt() {
    main = new JFrame();
    tl1 = new TextListener();
    ts1 = new TextSource();

    main.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    main.add(tl1);
    main.add(ts1);

    main.revalidate();
    main.repaint();
    main.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 900));
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    main.setVisible(true);
}
```

[I packed the main JFrame after adding the two JPanel's but it still shows just the top bar of a windows page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6A8X.png)

Comment: Do your classes have anything beyond constructors?

Comment: yes they have methods but they don't have anything to do with the GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with a little analysis first

In `JFrameExt` you have...

```
tl1 = new TextListener();
ts1 = new TextSource();
//...
main.add(tl1);
main.add(ts1)
```

So, lets have a look at `TextListener`

```
public TextListener() {
    newText = new TextSource();
    jp1 = new JPanel();
    stuff = new JTextArea(45, 70);
    scroll = new JScrollPane(stuff);

    stuff.setEditable(false);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    jp1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jp1.add(stuff);
    jp1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    jp1.setVisible(true);

    JFrame yo = new JFrame();
    yo.add(jp1);
    yo.setVisible(true);
}
```

Okay, assuming that code compiles, we can assume that `TextListener` is some kind of component, but you never actually add anything to it

Lets have a look at `TextSource`

```
public TextSource() {
    jp1 = new JPanel();
    tf1 = new JTextField(8);
    lb1 = new JLabel("Text Source");

    jp1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    jp1.add(tf1);
    jp1.add(lb1);

    jp1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    jp1.setVisible(true);

    tf1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            newTextFirer(tf1.getText());
        }
    });

    JFrame yo = new JFrame();
    yo.add(jp1);
    yo.setVisible(true);
}
```

Hmmm, same problem.

So based on these out-of-context snippets of code, you should have three windows, two of which have no defined size

Lets see if we can fix the core problems, lets start with `TextListener`.  Since we can assume `TextListener` is some kind of component, instead of adding stuff to a new `JFrame`, simply add it directly to the component itself, for example...

```
public TextListener() {
    newText = new TextSource();
    stuff = new JTextArea(45, 70);
    scroll = new JScrollPane(stuff);

    stuff.setEditable(false);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(stuff);
    setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
}
```

You'll have to update `TextSource` in a similar way.

Now back to `JFrameExt`.  You don't need to `revalidate` or `repaint` the frame, it's not been realised on the screen, so it's rather useless. `setSize` is just a bad practice and you should use `pack` instead, for example...

```
public JFrameExt() {
    main = new JFrame();
    tl1 = new TextListener();
    ts1 = new TextSource();

    main.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    main.add(tl1);
    main.add(ts1);

    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.pack();
    main.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    main.setVisible(true);
}
```

Now, if after you've applied these changes and it doesn't "seem to work", I recommend instead of out-of-context code snippets which require use to make guesses and assumptions, you provide an actually runnable example which demonstrates your problem

## Updated with runnable example...

So, I took your code, applied the suggested changes and wrapped into a runnable example ...

[image: See how it works]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                TextListener tl1 = new TextListener();
                TextSource ts1 = new TextSource();
                frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                frame.add(tl1);
                frame.add(ts1);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TextListener extends JPanel {

        public TextListener() {
            JTextArea stuff = new JTextArea(45, 70);
            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(stuff);

            stuff.setEditable(false);
            scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            add(stuff);
            setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }
    }

    public class TextSource extends JPanel {

        public TextSource() {
            JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(8);
            JLabel lb1 = new JLabel("Text Source");

            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            add(tf1);
            add(lb1);

            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, the two JFrames I have in textlistener and textsource were to see if the jpanel's did not have a defined size, the revalidate and repaint were just me messing around.  sorry for the messy code.

Comment: my main problem is that when I run, the code, the two jpanel's do not receive a defined size, I was wondering if that was the flowlayout's problem? and how do I fix that without using setsize? I used pack but it didn't do anything.

Comment: @Brandon The two “extra” frames haven’t been packed, so no layout pass has been run, so they will default to 0x0

Comment: sorry, could you check my edit please, I showed a screenshot of what was happening.

Comment: @Brandon Check my edit, because it works.  A component can only reside on a single container, if you try adding them to other containers, they are first removed from their current container, which would explain, in part, you problem.  Also, as I explained, you don't actually add anything to either `TextListener` or `TextSource`. If you continue to have issues, the I would demand that you create a runnable example which demonstrates your problem, so I can stop guessing at what you're doing

Comment: oh so my problem was I created components and put them in one container, but I then tried to add them to another container which you can't do?

Comment: @Brandon And you the components you did add to the frame (`TextListener`/`TextSource`) were empty, because you actually never added anything to them, `jp1` is kind of useless assuming that the parent classes are components

Comment: Okay that helps, I fixed it now.  Thanks!